# Why does String::isEmpty works when non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context?

Tags: java, java-8

I understand the error message. I know that I cannot access non-static methods in a static context. But why I can do the following:

```
Predicate<String> t = String::isEmpty; // this works
```

When isEmpty() is a non-static method for the class String? Look at the following example class. I understand the logic to not allow TestLamba::isEmptyTest; **but what I don't understand is why String:isEmpty can break this rule:**

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class TestLamba {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Predicate<String> t = String::isEmpty; // this works
        Predicate<String> t2 = TestLamba::isEmptyTest; // this doesn't
    }

    public boolean isEmptyTest() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the source for String.isEmpty. It's a pretty common method and you can see that it is not static:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.value.length == 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you think the `String` from `Predicate<String>` would go when using `TestLamba::isEmptyTest`?

Comment: You are accessing `TestLamba`'s non-static method in `TestLamba`'s static method; and accessing `String`'s non-static method in `TestLamba`'s static method instead of accessing `String`'s non-static method in `String`'s static method.

Comment: If you subclass `String` and create a static method that access `String::isEmpty`, you should get your expected outcome

Comment: @RickyMo `String` cannot be subclassed.

Comment: So I should say 'If you can ever subclass `String`' ... since this is not the case so the expected outcome never happens

Comment: When in doubt, try this out => Type using lambdas `Predicate<String> p2 = t -> t. <someMethod>`..you'll get to notice both the type of `t` and the available merthods that you can reference.

Comment: Note that a static method reference is a different concept than accessing non-static methods from a static context. Like nullpointer already said, `String::isEmpty` is equal to `(String t) -> t.isEmpty()`, and if you're writing it like this, there's nothing static at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`isEmpty` is the function of `String` Class and `isEmptyTest` is the function of  `TestLamba`  class.

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class TestLamba {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Predicate<String> t = String::isEmpty; // this works
        Predicate<TestLamba > t2 = TestLamba::isEmptyTest; //Now this will work
    }

    public boolean isEmptyTest() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't realize that the generic parameter was the reference class. Thanks!